# Legitimacy of selling חמץ

Tags: passover, halacha-theory, selling-mechirat-chametz

What are the arguments for and against the now-widespread practice of selling חמץ prior to פסח?

Comment: Page 4: http://www.derher.org/uploads/1/6/8/2/16823364/0111_-_derher_metzora.pdf - it includes a short history.

Comment: See "Moadim Behalacha" (R' Zevin) for a great overview of the history and controversies of "Mechiras Chometz". (If I get some time I'll try make it into an answer).

Answer (score 3):

This idea is old: its origin comes from a Tosefta in Pesahchim: see Aruch Hashulchan 448:16. The Ritva, pesachim 21, is of the opinion that selling and buying back every year is not good. The Shulchan Aruch does not cite the Ritva. One should not say our sales are not real and a trick: see the Chasam Sofer OC 113 about this. Also see the Bach 448.